# How to write Junit Test for particular file present in specified location or not?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, primefaces, junit4

By using *junit* test case how to check that particular file either present at specified location or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a test that checks the following:

> new File(filePath).exists()

In case its false just throw an exception

You should take a look at the  [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) Class